# Amazon Report API - Downloaded Text File Occasional Corruption

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using the Amazon MWS API to download a text file containing orders.  70% of the time the file downloads perfectly but sometime I get corruption.  If I look at the file via the Amazon web front end it looks fine. However by the time it is stored on the local hard drive it can be corrupted.  I can see no pattern as to why some file have this problem and others don't.

The corruption I am talking about looks like this (data changed but highlights the problem)

```
payments-status order-id    order-item-id   payments-date   payments-transaction-id item-name   listing-id  sku price   shipping-fee    quantity-purchased  total-price purchase-date   batch-id    buyer-email buyer-name  recipient-name  ship-address-1  ship-address-2  ship-city   ship-state  ship-zip    ship-country    special-comments    upc ship-method sales-channel   VAT
    205-2599941-6954759 11274234567395  07/01/2015 15:22:48 Europe/London       My Product 1    1128h56V4X  9785858599053   3.59    2.8 1   6.39    07/01/2015 15:22:48 Europe/London       bwfdsfs3tmf15w@marketplace.amazon.co.uk Mr F Bloggs Mr Fred Bloggs  My Cottage  XXXXXXX AnyTown Isle of Man XX1 2XX GB          standard        
    205-499978-7575554  68198765457651  07/01/2015 15:28:23 Europe/London       My Product 2    1128h56MWN9 9785858524633   5.99    2.8 1   8.79    07/01/2015 15:28:23 Europe/London       zyrre44rrr7nk@marketplace.amazon.co.uk  Jane Bloggs Prof Jane Blogs Her Cottage, XXXXXXX        AnyTown Surrey  XX1 2XX GB          standard        
.99 2.8 1   8.79    07/01/2015 14:07:33 Europe/London       nuy76sz9fw4lzk@marketplace.amazon.co.uk Joe Bloggs  Joe Bloggs  71  The Houses  AnyTown MyCounty    AA1 1WW GB          standard        
    026-199993-8483529  38758765432635  07/01/2015 14:07:05 Europe/London       My Product 3 ...    118h56QMBQR 9781783610433   5.99    2.8 1   8.79    07/01/2015 14:07:05 Europe/London       h0hx8werwew4t4@marketplace.amazon.co.uk Claire Blogs    Claire Bloggs   XXXXXXX AnyTown JERSEY  Channel Islands XX1 2XX GB          standard        
    202-788880-2669961  46830987654327  07/01/2015 14:22:21 Europe/London       My Product 4    1128h56V89  978585856766    3.59    2.8 1   6.39    07/01/2015 14:22:21 Europe/London       w608ewrwewrk74l@marketplace.amazon.co.uk    Harry Blogs Harry Bloggs    XXXXXXX     AnyTown Co Durham   XX1 2XX GB          standard        
    203-355556-3369905  34856789098939  07/01/2015 14:24:42 Europe/London       My Product 5    118h56QLX1L 9785858512400   5.99    2.8 1   8.79    07/01/2015 14:24:42 Europe/London       zgw0rwewere98y@marketplace.amazon.co.uk Aimee Blogs Aimee Bloggs    XXXXXXX 25 Any Street   AnyTown     XX1 2XX GB          standard        
    204-4888812-4296349 14153456784747  07/01/2015 14:41:10 Europe/London       My Product 6    11278h5665F 9785858546360   3.59    2.8 1   6.39    07/01/2015 14:41:10 Europe/London       h5mcwerwewwwfvrg3@marketplace.amazon.co.uk  Julie Bloggs    Julie Bloggs    XXXXXXX     AnyTown Devon   XX1 2XX GB          standard        
    026-1666655-8765
```

This is a tab delimited file and the first column is always a blank field.  The first two lines show correct data and in a real file there are plenty of correct lines before I see this happen.  The 3rd line is missing a number of columns from the start of the line and the last line is missing part of the second field and all the rest of the columns.

I see this happening mainly towards the end of the file.

So the code I use is the library straight from the Amazon site [Reports C# API](https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/doc/bde/reports/v20090901/cSharp.html):

```
private T Invoke<T, K>(IDictionary<String, String> parameters, K clazz)
{

    String actionName = parameters["Action"];
    T response = default(T);
    String responseBody = null;
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = default(HttpStatusCode);
    ResponseHeaderMetadata rhm = null;

    // Verify service URL is set.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(config.ServiceURL))
    {
        throw new MarketplaceWebServiceException(new ArgumentException(
            "Missing serviceUrl configuration value. You may obtain a list of valid MWS URLs by consulting the MWS Developer's Guide, or reviewing the sample code published along side this library."));      
    }

    /* Add required request parameters */
    AddRequiredParameters(parameters);

    String queryString = GetParametersAsString(parameters);
    byte[] requestData = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(queryString);

    HttpWebRequest request;

    bool isStreamingResponse = ExpectStreamingResponse(typeof(K));

    bool shouldRetry = true;
    int retries = 0;
    do
    {
        /* Submit the request and read response body */
        try
        {
            RequestType requestType = GetMarketplaceWebServiceRequestType(typeof(K));
            switch (requestType)
            {
                case RequestType.STREAMING:
                    {
                        SubmitFeedRequest req = clazz as SubmitFeedRequest;
                        if (req != null)
                        {
                            // SubmitFeedRequests can configure the content type.
                            request = ConfigureWebRequest(queryString, req.ContentType);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Send request using a default content-type.
                            request = ConfigureWebRequest(queryString, new ContentType(MediaType.OctetStream));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    request = ConfigureWebRequest(requestData.Length);
                    break;
            }

            WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;
            IDictionary<String, String> headerMap = GetHttpHeaderValues(clazz);
            foreach (String key in headerMap.Keys)
            {
                headers.Add(key, headerMap[key]);
            }

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                switch (requestType)
                {
                    case RequestType.STREAMING:
                        Stream inputStream = GetTransferStream(clazz, StreamType.REQUEST_STREAM);
                        inputStream.Position = 0;
                        CopyStream(inputStream, requestStream);
                        break;
                    default:
                        requestStream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
                        break;
                }
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
                rhm = new ResponseHeaderMetadata(
                    httpResponse.GetResponseHeader("x-mws-request-id"),
                    httpResponse.GetResponseHeader("x-mws-response-context"),
                    httpResponse.GetResponseHeader("x-mws-timestamp"));

                if (isStreamingResponse && statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    response = HandleStreamingResponse<T>(httpResponse, clazz);
                }
                else
                {

                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                    responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    XmlSerializer serlizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    response = (T)serlizer.Deserialize(new StringReader(responseBody));
                }

                PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty("ResponseHeaderMetadata");
                pi.SetValue(response, rhm, null);

                shouldRetry = false;
            }

            /* Attempt to deserialize response into <Action> Response type */

        }
        /* Web exception is thrown on unsucessful responses */
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            shouldRetry = false;
            using (HttpWebResponse httpErrorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (httpErrorResponse == null)
                {
                    throw new MarketplaceWebServiceException(we);
                }
                statusCode = httpErrorResponse.StatusCode;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpErrorResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            /* Attempt to deserialize response into ErrorResponse type */
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serlizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ErrorResponse));
                ErrorResponse errorResponse = (ErrorResponse)serlizer.Deserialize(new StringReader(responseBody));
                Error error = errorResponse.Error[0];

                bool retriableError = (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError || statusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
                retriableError = retriableError && error.Code != "RequestThrottled";

                if (retriableError && retries < config.MaxErrorRetry)
                {
                    PauseOnRetry(++retries);
                    shouldRetry = true;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    shouldRetry = false;
                }

                /* Throw formatted exception with information available from the error response */
                throw new MarketplaceWebServiceException(
                    error.Message,
                    statusCode,
                    error.Code,
                    error.Type,
                    errorResponse.RequestId,
                    errorResponse.ToXML(),
                    rhm);
            }
            /* Rethrow on deserializer error */
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e is MarketplaceWebServiceException)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                else
                {
                    MarketplaceWebServiceException se = ReportAnyErrors(responseBody, statusCode, e, rhm);
                    throw se;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Catch other exceptions, attempt to convert to formatted exception,
         * else rethrow wrapped exception */
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new MarketplaceWebServiceException(e);
        }
    } while (shouldRetry);

    return response;
}
```

These are the values being passed in:

```
    -       parameters  Count = 3   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string> {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>}
+       [0] {[Action, GetReport]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>
+       [1] {[Merchant, A999AAAA7KT4OI]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>
+       [2] {[ReportId, 59999999994]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>


-       clazz   {MyCompany.MyApp.Amazon.MarketplaceWebService.Model.GetReportRequest}   MyCompany.MyApp.Amazon.MarketplaceWebService.Model.GetReportRequest
        Marketplace null    string
        marketplaceField    null    string
        Merchant    "A999AAAA7KT4OI"    string
        merchantField   "A999AAAA7KT4OI"    string
        MWSAuthToken    null    string
        mwsAuthTokenField   null    string
+       Report  {System.IO.FileStream}  System.IO.Stream {System.IO.FileStream}
+       report  {System.IO.FileStream}  System.IO.Stream {System.IO.FileStream}
        ReportId    "59999999994"   string
        reportIdField   "59999999994"   string
```

The resulting file is saved to disk.

When this problem first presented itself I tried to code a workaround while I looked for a reason and the correct fix. This is to open the file and loop through it line by line to ensure that each line start with a tab followed by 3 digits and a hyphen but now this doesn't work because of the last line.  Now I have a bit of time to try and get to the bottom of why this is happening.

I raised it with Amazon but they say that the problem is with my code (even though it is theirs) not parsing the file correctly.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening or point me in a direction I should be looking?

Comment: it looks like a linebreak issue from the previous line. It's a nonanswer, but it's the text version of code smell.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem.  The file I download to was `Amazon.txt`, over writing each time it ran. as soon as I changed this to be a unique file name the corruption problem disappeared.